# Adding onclick events dynamically to links within a specific div and other links in a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

How would I add an onclick event using Jquery or normal JavaScript to all links in a certain div. I have a div called canvas0_0 and I have links that look like this: `<a href="some-uri.htm">Open Popup</a>`. The event I need to add needs to look like the below:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'label',o,true]);"
```

Instead of label, I need a way for this to be unique rather pulling the link or the image name.

I also need this doing for any link that ends with .pdf or .zip, inside or out the div.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the href value instead of the label, so as you can track more precisely the link clicked.

Here, the selector handles clicks for links located within your canvas0_0 div, and all the links ending with .pdf and .zip. Note that if you have some links ending with .pdf or .zip INSIDE your canvas0_0 div, you should consider adding a stopImmediatePropagation() to avoid the doublie firing of the event

```
$(function(){
    $("#canvas0_0 a, a[href$='.pdf'], a[href$='.zip']").click(function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),o,true]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it for the first set of links:

```
$("#canvas0_0 a[href$='.htm']").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'label',o,true]);
});
```

For everything ending with `.pdf` or `.zip`:

```
$("a[href$='.pdf'], a[href$='.zip']").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'label',o,true]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your div (e.g. `<div class="click_track" ...> ... </div>`

now your jQuery to handle the click on the div looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.click_track').click(function()
    {
        // handle click here
    });
});
```